# Yeoman generator run async best practice

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, yeoman, yeoman-generator

Im creating a yeoman generator which is working ok, now I need to add a list
from async (I want it to run in background) call which can take about 2-3 sec to retrieve the data, so I put it inside the `initializing` as the user will get this question as the third question. (see object below) 
so the data retrieve process will start to avoid waiting when user hit question 3. basically I want that the data retrieval will done in a background process..

My question are:

1. Is they async usage handled ok ? I mean running async inside the `initialize` method

What I tried is the following:

```
export default class AppGenerator extends Generator {
    private listData: ListInstance[];


    async initializing() {
        this.props = {
            appName: "app",
            apiName: "app-api",
        };
        //--------------Here I call to async function --------------//
        this.listData = await GetInstances();
    }

    async prompting() {
        const answers = await this.prompt([
            {
                name: "appName",
                message: "Project name: ",
                type: "input",
                default: this.props.appName,

            },
            {
                name: "apiName",
                message: "API name: ",
                type: "input",
                default: this.props.apiName,
            },
            {
                name: "instanceName",
                type: "list",
                message: "Choose instance",
                choices: this.listData,
            },
        ];
    }

writing() {

//here I dont get the `this.answers` , I need to get the values from the answers

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details...like the HTML and events which are being fired.. I  am a little confused about where the issue is... The flow of application... How things are working and what is this prompting function doing? I can't understand much with the snippet that you shared.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal - lets say you are creating and yeoman generator, and one of the question should return a list of data from rest call (which can take 1-3 seconds) , and you want to run this process in the background that when the user hit this question he doesnt needs to wait for 3 seconds to get the data, how would you do it ?

Comment: That I get it but .. are you making any http requests or from service or some other way..and if it on initialization.... will it fetch  next 3 questions as you said..it need to be running in background.. so I am unable to understand the flow. If you can clear that.. I'll happy to help you in a better way...

Comment: @HimanshuBansal - the service is calling to local API (its not public..) `lets assume its a function that you are calling to some rest which take about 3 seconds (or more, network....) and the data should be fetch at the initialization as we dont want to waste time, but it should be ready on question 3 `instanceName`  how would you do it? worker thread ? the `instanceName` need to access this data

Comment: @HimanshuBansal - is it clearer now ?

Comment: got it... Give me some time.. i just got free from office... Let me create a fiddle for you so that you can verify if it is working or not ok?

Comment: @HimanshuBansal - sure no problem

Answer (score 0):

First some observations:

- Yeoman Uses Inquirer.js [1](https://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html#remembering-user-preferences)
- Inquirer.js has reactive prompting [2](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#reactive-interface)
- finally, I have not tested this code. Please excuse or point out bugs

also, make sure your answers are accessible outside of the Prompting method (i.e. using the `this` for the class - used in example)

```js
...
    async prompting() {
        var prompts = new Rx.Subject();
        this.prompt(prompts);
        prompts.next({
            name: "appName",
            message: "Project name: ",
            type: "input",
            default: this.props.appName,
        });
        prompts.next({
            name: "apiName",
            message: "API name: ",
            type: "input",
            default: this.props.apiName,

        });
        this.listData = await GetInstances();
        prompts.next({

            name: "instanceName",
            type: "list",
            message: "Choose instance",
            choices: this.listData,

        });
        prompts.complete();
        this.answers = this.prompt(prompts).ui.process.subscribe(onEachAnswer, onError, onComplete);
    }
...
```

> Other notes: The use of `await` will start the call to `GetInstances` when the `Prompting` section is started. However, it will not allow the final question to be asked until `GetInstances` has returned.

---

[1: Yeoman uses Inquirer.js](https://yeoman.io/authoring/user-interactions.html#remembering-user-preferences)

[2: Reactive Prompting in Inquirer.js](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/#reactive-interface)